# Redux - Exception in Reducer causes broken store

Tags: javascript, redux

Recently we have been having some exceptions occurring in our Reducer code.  This has resulted in a broken store.  All subsequent action/reducers that get initiated do not work.  The store ends up in a broken state.

Is there any way to add a global redux store exception handler?  Some sort of middle-ware to the redux store?

Am I approaching Redux incorrectly?

Comment: do you have many logics in reducers? according to instructions from redux so reducers should be predictable so consider to reduce the complexity in the reducers it can help to reduce exceptions as well

Comment: We do have logic in the reducers.  I agree this is not ideal, and probably qualifies as me not using redux correctly.  However, I still would like to see if it's possible to expose that an exception has happened in the store.

Comment: I dont know if there is any official middleware but I can think of a solution in combineReducer, you can add an arrow function that wraps your reducer with try/catch there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this: https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware

```
function patchStoreToAddCrashReporting(store) {
  const next = store.dispatch
  store.dispatch = function dispatchAndReportErrors(action) {
    try {
      return next(action)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Caught an exception!', err)
      Raven.captureException(err, {
        extra: {
          action,
          state: store.getState()
        }
      })
      throw err
    }
  }
}
```